# Issue with passing an array of URL's

Tags: ios, swift

I am parsing a `json` response to get about 10 URL's of images. I am getting those in `imageURL` as given below in the 2nd code snippet. Now when I had to show an image to the collection view by just specifying an URL, I did it like so...

```
let myImgUrl = "http://myapp…..”

let url = URL(string: imageurl)
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
self.sampleImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
self.arrayOfURLImages.append(self.sampleImageView.image!)
```

//-------Getting `imageURL` here---------

```
if let projectData = jsonDict["Productdata"] as? [[String: Any]] {
    let productIds = projectData.flatMap({ $0["product_id"] as? String })
    let images = projectData.flatMap({ $0["product_images"] as? [[String: Any]] }).flatMap({ $0 })
    let imageURL = images.flatMap({ $0["image_url"] as? String })

}
```

Now I have to assign `imageURL` to `myImgUrl`. And if I directly pass imageURL, it gives the error..`'Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String''`. How can I fix this...?

Also, this is the `json` response..

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "TotalRevenue": “123.12 K",
    "Productdata": [
        {
            "product_id": "5",
            "product_name": “abc”
            "product_images": [
                {
                    "id": "938",
                    "image_url": "http://myApp.direct.com/public165_1_image_15",
                    "is_default": "1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "939",
                    "image_url": "http://myApp.direct.com/public165_1_image_16",
                    "is_default": "0"
                }

            ]
        }
```

Comment: You have to define your object as let myImgUrl = [String]. Then you can assign  imageURL to myImgUrl.

Comment: `flatMap` returns an array, while you are looking for a `String`, please show an sample JSON so that we can help you more.

Comment: @Nikhil Manapure I have edited the question by adding the json response also

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a mac right now, but please try my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`flatMap` returns an array of its type. In this case, it returns a `[String]`. `myImgUrl` in your code is a constant that holds a `String`, not a `[String]`. You'll have to get a *specific* `String` out of `imageURL` and assign it to `myImgUrl`. That being said, with the code you've pasted, that will fail because `myImgUrl` is a `let` constant, whose value you cannot reassign by definition. If the string from `imageURL` is the first value that `myImgUrl` will ever have, then everything's ok, but if you're initializing `myImgUrl` with something else first, you'll have to use `var` instead of `let`

Comment: But @Michael Hulet, how can I get a specific String out of imageURL as you said so that I can assign it to myImgUrl..?

Comment: You should probably read more in the [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309). With Swift arrays, you can access its members with subscripts, like so: `imageURL[0] // Gets the first string in the imageURL array`

Answer (score 0):

For setting imageurls

```
   if let projectData = jsonDict["Productdata"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        // Rest of the "getting the data"
        let images = projectData["product_images"] as? NSArray
        let imageURLs = images.flatMap({ $0["image_url"] as? String }) // You will need an instance var here.
    }
```

For getting url

```
url = imageURLs[indexPath.row]
```

I suggest you to use Models to make your code more readable and error free. :)

[This website](http://www.json4swift.com/) helps a lot for using models.